# Disabling any possibility to exit a software?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, kiosk

I am implementing university exam software in `C++`, and I want to prevent any person from the ability to close it once it runs. The purpose is to prevent the user from copying the software, printing the screen and saving it, and other purposes!

I was initially thinking about a way of disabling <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, and other key combinations, but apparently following this approach is not that easy especially in versions after windows xp.

What do you think a viable approach to solve my problem ?

Comment: Perhaps writing a small TSR which checks every key pressed might be good. You simply break the interrupt chain if you detect combinations such as those you mentioned. It's quite a low level stuff though.

Comment: What you are describing is impossible within the scope of a user mode application.  If you wish to write a kernel driver which would make this possible, congratulations, you basically just made a root kit...

Comment: @BlackBear A DOS TSR??? Wow!!! Perhaps I still have my copy of Sidekick!

Comment: @Benj It wouldn't be a root kit. The Wiki definition is `A rootkit is software that enables continued privileged access to a computer while actively hiding its presence from administrators by subverting standard operating system functionality or other applications.`. I would say `a better keyboard driver` :-)

Comment: True, not really a root kit, but certainly sharing some charactoristics...

Comment: @Louis What you are speaking about is normally called "kiosk mode". perhaps there are guides/programs to do it.

Comment: Can't be done as described. Whatever you try, I can always pull the power cord.

Comment: And you could start from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617303/does-windows-7-have-a-kiosk-mode

Comment: @xanatos, even the MS IE kiosk mode doesn't support disabling Ctrl-alt-del http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780

Comment: @Benj That page is of Windows 95!! Do you want my copy of Sidekick? And it was a "kiosk mode" very simple. The special keys weren't disabled (even ALT-TAB)

Comment: @xantos It sounds like a (post win95 ;-)) true kiosk mode requires the use of a kernel driver...  it does look like such drivers exist already though...

Comment: Thank you all for your input. @Widor pulling the power cord is fine as the computer will restart and the computer is password protected.

Comment: @xanatos: your help is very much appreciated. I will follow your idea and read about Kiosk. Many thanks.

Comment: You can always glue a few keys in your keyboard. Maybe both Alt keys are enough for that.

Answer (score 5):

You should of course take all the normal steps of making your application refuse to close by itself (perhaps unless a password is provided), so we 're only talking about the "I don't want to allow anyone to forcefully close it" part.

One solution would be to make your app be the Windows shell.

Another solution would be to set up the computer such that the currently logged in user has no permission to shut your application down.

And a final solution, which is a dirty, not officially supported hack you didn't hear from me, is to do this:

```
public static class Utility
{
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void RtlSetProcessIsCritical(UInt32 v1, UInt32 v2, UInt32 v3);

    public static void BsodIfProcessEnds()
    {
        Process.EnterDebugMode();
        RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void NoFireworksIfProcessEnds()
    {
        RtlSetProcessIsCritical(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Warning: `BsodIfProcessEnds` does exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: Hehe, I like the idea that the student doing the exam is presented with an immediate BSOD if they try to close the test, sweet... ;-)

Comment: Many thanks Jon. The second option is not really possible as I have to convince the university to change the settings for their computers. I will check the windows shell idea and your code. But first i will try to understand the code :) Many thanks.

Comment: @Louis: `RtlSetProcessIsCritical` is an undocumented function call that Windows uses to mark some processes of its own as critical (and BSOD you if one of them dies, which should be never).

Comment: +1 for the most diabolical solution to a problem I've ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

Give users only a restricted user account on the machine, and don't give them permissions to kill your application.

Do the same for your other restrictions, and you don't even need to write an app.

If you want users to run as administrators, what you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this is not really possible for me as the computers are university computers. It is not really an easy option to convicne the department to change the settings for their computers :)

Answer (score 0):

You might create two apps.
One is constantly checking if your app is running
If it is not running then start it, this could be a service (harder to spot for simple users).

You might do some fun with NTFS permission too.
For example create an upper directory where the user has no permissions at all (not even viewing its content) then create under that a folder where the user has read permissions.
Unless the user knows a good geus it becomes a bit harder to find your app.

But still he could launch taskmanager but perhaps there is a policy against that.
Speaking of which with policies you can make it so restricted that he is only allowed to run your app and not any other app (so he wont be able to copy it, or use the PC for anything else then your app.